# Single Lambda@Edge function invocation on both viewer request and viewer reponse

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge, amazon-cloudfront

I currently have two Lambda@Edge functions:

- language-redirect: invoked on viewer request, returns a 302 or passes the request on to CloudFront
- HSTS: invoked on viewer response, adds response header

The current flow is:

```
viewer request -> language-redirect

if 302 -> viewer response
if not 302 -> pass on to CloudFront -> HSTS -> viewer response
```

Would it be possible to combine both in one function (combined) that is invoked only a single time per viewer request?

```
viewer request -> combined

if 302 -> viewer response
if not 302 -> pass on to CloudFront -> combined -> viewer response
```

The goal is to have the same function invoked once, not having the same function invoked twice.

Answer (score 7):

There are 4 distinct trigger events in CloudFront's Lambda@Edge enhancement.  Their interaction with the cache is in bold, and becomes important, later:

- Viewer Request - fires on every request, before the cache is checked on request arrival; **a spontaneously-generated response is not cached**
- Origin Request - fires only on cache miss, before request goes to the origin; **if this trigger generates a response, no HTTP request is sent to the origin, and the response will be stored in the cache, if cacheable**
- Origin Response - fires only on cache miss, when response returns from origin, before response is checked for cacheability and stored in the cache; **if this trigger modifies the response, the modified response is what is stored in the cache, if cacheable**
- Viewer Response - fires immediately before response is returned to viewer, whether cache hit or miss; **any modifications to the response made by this trigger are not cached**

One Lambda function, correctly written to understand where it has been fired within the transaction cycle, can be triggered at any combination of these points -- but since *these events all occur at different times*, it isn't possible to handle more than a single event with one invocation of the trigger function.

**However**, note the points in bold, above.  You can substantially reduce the number of trigger invocations in many cases by using the origin-side triggers.  As noted above, using these triggers results in the response of the triggers being cacheable -- so when your redirect trigger fires, if it generates a redirect, the redirect can be cached, and the next request doesn't need to invoke the trigger at all.  Similarly, adding your HSTS header to a cacheable response in an origin response trigger means that future cache hits will return the modified response with HSTS headers, without the trigger firing.

---

Update: in 2021, CloudFront (finally!) launched a new feature called [response header policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-response-headers-policies/), which allows you to configure static HTTP response headers as part of the CloudFront distribution.  This allows adding of static response headers, such as for HSTS (as mentioned in the original question), without using Lambda@Edge or CloudFront Functions.

Comment: What I was thinking is, if instead of "return callback(null, request)" at the end of the function, one would do something like "response = callback(null, request)" one might be able to manipulate the response once CloudFront has generated it. Thoughts?

Comment: Nothing like that is possible.  To manipulate the response, you have no alternative but to fire a response trigger.

Comment: Thank you for the great response.  I do have a question about what you stated under "Origin Request".  You said "if this trigger generates a response".  What is the right way to not generate a response -- to tell CloudFront to go ahead and send the request to the origin (like a passthrough lambda)?

Comment: @Raff if you set the return value from the lambda function to `event.Records[0].cf.request`, CloudFront will resume processing and forward the request to the origin.  In some use cases, you can optionally modify that request object within the lambda function and doing that will modify what CloudFront actually sends to the origin (e.g. you can manipulate the headers or cookies that the origin will ultimately see).

Comment: @sqlbot Thank you.  I appreciate the reply.  Would you mind taking a look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843453/aws-lambdaedge-viewer-request-fails-with-the-body-is-not-a-string-is-not-an-o 
I have. a bounty out for this one.