# AWS Lambda@Edge Viewer Request fails with 'The body is not a string, is not an object, or exceeds the maximum size'

Tags: angular, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda@Edge function to return Open Graph HTML for my Angular SPA application.  I've installed it into the CloudFrond "Viewer Request" lifecycle.  This lambda checks the user agent, and if it's the Facebook or Twitter crawler, it returns HTML (currently hard coded in the lambda for testing).  If the request is from any other user-agent, the request is passed through to the origin.  The pass-through logic is working properly, but if I try to intercept and return the Open Graph HTML for the crawlers, I get an error.

In CloudWatch, the error reported by CloudFront is:

> ERROR Validation error: The Lambda function returned an invalid body,
> body should be of object type.

In Postman (by faking the user-agent), I get a 502 with:

> The Lambda function result failed validation: The body is not a
> string, is not an object, or exceeds the maximum size.

I'm pulling my hair out with this one.  Any ideas?  Here's my lambda.

```js
'use strict';
 
function buildReleaseResponse( request ) {
     
    const content = `<\!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
               
                <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
                <meta property="og:title" content="Hello, World" />
                <meta property="og:description" content="This is an Open Graph test" />
                <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.website.com/photos/SGmzAlNmwOGpnMeijMoW9.jpg" />
                <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.website.com/hello-world" />
               
                <title>Hello, World</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Open Graph Test</h1>
            </body>
        </html>`;
   
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        statusDescription: 'OK',
        headers: {
            "content-type": [
                {
                    "key": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
                }
            ]
        },
        body: content.toString()
    };
   
}
 

exports.handler = ( event, context, callback ) => {
    const { request, response } = event.Records[0].cf;
                                           
    let userAgentStr = "";
       
    if (request.headers['user-agent']) {
      if (request.headers['user-agent'].length > 0) {
          userAgentStr = request.headers['user-agent'][0].value;
      }
    }
   
    let newResponse = null;
   
    if ( userAgentStr.match(/facebookexternalhit|twitterbot/i) ) {
        if ( request.uri.startsWith("/radio/release/") ) {
            newResponse = buildReleaseResponse(request);
        }
    }
   
    if ( newResponse === null ) {
        console.log("Passthrough.");
        callback(null, request);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Overriding response with: " + JSON.stringify(newResponse));
        callback(null, newResponse);
    }   
};
```

Here is the response shown in cloudwatch (conole.log)

```js
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusDescription": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": [{
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        }],
        "cache-control": [{
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=100"
        }]
    },
    "body": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n            <html lang=\"en\">\n                <head>\n                    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>\n                    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />\n                    \n                    <meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"website\" />\n                    <meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"Yo Dog\" />\n                    <meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"Song by Raf Fiol and Mike Patterson\" />\n                    <meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"https://cdn.kompoz.com/photos/SGmzAlNmwOGpnMeijMoW9.jpeg\" />\n                    <meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"https://3-www.kompoz.com/radio/release/yo_dog\" />\n                    \n                    <title>Kompoz.com</title>\n                </head>\n                <body>\n                    <h1>Yo Dog</h1>\n                </body>\n            </html>"
}
```

Here is the CloudFront Lambda configuration

[image: CloudFront Lambda configuration]

Comment: What does your `console.log` output show to be contained in  `newResponse`?

Comment: I see there is a small difference with the example in the AWS docs. They escape the `!` char in the DOCTYPE. I suppose it might be worth trying it as well

Comment: @Sergey Great eye.  I tried that just now but unfortunately that did not solve it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I Added the console.log output (from CloudWatch logs) to my question above.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify body encoding

Comment: This could be a problem with your Behavior configuration. Could you post a screenshot of your Lambda Function Association?

Comment: @kgiannakakis I just posted a screenshot.  Thank you for the suggestion and for looking into this.

Comment: Try unchecking "Include Body", as you don't need it. According to the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-include-body-access.html), it is meant to be used with writable HTTP methods and not GET requests.

Comment: @kgiannakakis Thanks again.  Just tried unchecking "include body", waited for CloudFront to Invalidate/Deploy, but it still fails.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**SOLVED**!  I'm embarrassed to report that this issue is caused by a typo on my part.  In my response object, I had:

```
"statusCode": 200,
```

But it should have been:

```
"status": 200,
```

Happy to report that it is now working.  Having said that, I wish that the AWS error message was better.  The message "*The body is not a string, is not an object, or exceeds the maximum size*" really threw me off.

Comment: That's why I'm using TypeScript :D

Comment: @Sergey Can you please share where to get types for lambda @edge?

Comment: It's funny cuz i also used typescript but my type was defined for statusCode: number, lol

Comment: The strange thing is that the test code provided by default by AWS returns `statusCode`. One would expect that the default should be a working example, but it is not.

Comment: For 3 hours I was stuck on this problem, and it is because AWS incorrectly use `statusCode` in THEIR OWN EXAMPLE CODE?!? AWS documentation is literally beyond infurating...

Comment: It seems to be statusCode for normal lambda and status for lambdaEdge functions. AWS, keeping Dev's on their toes since March 2006.